# unity 3d editor crash when i put this code and press play, can you help me find the problem?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game for mobile devices and

I wanted to spawn random enemy in a random position, but when i put this code on my object and press play, the editor go crash. i checked the task manager but i cant see anything strange

```
float RandX;

public GameObject[] elenco = new GameObject[5];
GameObject ciao;
int indice;
float RandxV = 2f;
Vector2 whereToSpawn;
public int nEnemy = 2;
public GameObject entrata;
public GameObject uscita;

void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nEnemy; i++)
    {
        indice = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(0f, 4.0f));
        Debug.Log(indice);
        if (indice == 2)
        {
            spawnaPortale();
        }
        else
        {
            RandX = Random.Range(-0.9f, 0.9f);
            while (RandxV == RandX)
            {
                RandX = Random.Range(-0.9f, 0.9f);
            }
            ciao = (GameObject)elenco[indice];
            whereToSpawn = new Vector2(RandX, transform.position.y);
            Instantiate(ciao, whereToSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
            RandxV = RandX;
        }
    }
}

void spawnaPortale()
{
    float entrataX;
    float entrataY;
    float uscitaX;
    float uscitaY;

    entrataX = Random.Range(-0.9f, 0.9f);
    uscitaX = Random.Range(-0.9f, 0.9f);
    float diffx = entrataX - uscitaX;
    while (diffx < 0.3f || diffx > -0.3f)
    {
        uscitaX = Random.Range(-0.9f, 0.9f);
    }
    float valori = this.transform.position.y - 0.5f;
    entrataY = Random.Range(valori, this.transform.position.y);
    uscitaY = Random.Range(valori, this.transform.position.y);
    float diffy = entrataY - uscitaY;
    while (diffy < 0.3f || diffy > -0.3f)
    {
        uscitaY = Random.Range(valori, this.transform.position.y);
    }
    Vector2 whereToSpawnEntrata = new Vector2(entrataX, entrataY);
    Vector2 whereToSpawnUscita = new Vector2(uscitaX, uscitaY);
    Instantiate(entrata, whereToSpawnEntrata, Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(uscita, whereToSpawnUscita, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

This code should spawn random enemy but it crash

Comment: Hi Straww. Welcome to Stackoverflow! In my opinion, it would increase your chance of getting help here if you can organize and indent your code better. It is really hard to read it now. Also i suggest looking at Unity logs to find out what causes the problem if Unity crashes. Good Luck!

Comment: @Straww it's propably one of your `while` loops that runs without breaking. Double check them for errors.
Also: format your code man. If you want people to help you with your problem you should at least have the time to correctly indent and format your code before you post it here. You can find a C# styleguide [here](https://github.com/raywenderlich/c-sharp-style-guide)

Comment: @TehMightyPotato thanks a lot for this edit

Comment: @derHugo no problem. Copy&Paste into VisualStudio + autoformat does the trick most of the time.

Comment: @TehMightyPotato I know ;) but I'm on a smartphone :'D

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

In `spawnaPortale` you have two `while` loops like

```
float diffx = entrataX - uscitaX;
while(diffx < 0.3f || diffx > -0.3f)
{
    uscitaX = Random.Range(-0.9f, 0.9f);
}

// ...

float diffy = entrataY - uscitaY;
while(diffy < 0.3f || diffy > -0.3f)
{
    uscitaY = Random.Range(valori, this.transform.position.y);
}
```

but inside of the loops you **never update** the values of `diffx` and `diffy` so they will allways have the **same** value - namely those they had before entering the loops ... so once one of the two `while` conditions is `true` it will allways stay `true` => you are **forever** trapped in the loop.

---

**Fix:**

Update the values inside of the `while` loops

```
float diffx = entrataX - uscitaX;
while(diffx < 0.3f || diffx > -0.3f)
{
    uscitaX = Random.Range(-0.9f, 0.9f);
    diffx = entrataX - uscitaX;
}

// ...

float diffy = entrataY - uscitaY;
while(diffy < 0.3f || diffy > -0.3f)
{
    uscitaY = Random.Range(valori, this.transform.position.y);
    diffy = entrataY - uscitaY;
}
```

---

**Hint**

if for `diffx` and `diffy` you use [Math.Abs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Abs.html) instead like

```
float diffx = Mathf.Abs(entrataX - uscitaX);
```

your `while` conditions get way esier to interpret:

```
while(diffx < 0.3f)
{ 
    ... 
}
```

---

**Also note:**

Never use `==` to directly compare two float values!

Due to [single floating point precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) two float values are most of the time not equal

so your `while` condition in `Start` will probably **never** be `true`!

> Floating point imprecision makes comparing floats using the equals operator inaccurate. For example, (1.0 == 10.0 / 10.0) might not return true every time.

In the first condition it is okey to use `==` since you parse to `int` first. But when comparing `float` values allways use [Mathf.Approximately](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) like

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(RandxV , RandX))
```

> Approximately() compares two floats and returns true if they are within a small value (Epsilon) of each other.

Or at least define a range within which you consider two values to be equal like

```
if(Math.Abs(RandxV - RandX) < 0.0001f)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are executing a function with for() but in this function you use while() so unity crash. Try using if instead of while. This is like putting a loop inside the update() function.